# How to create private model field in Django?

Tags: django

Is there any way, to create a private field in Django. I want this field be accessible only from this class's methods.

Here is example of what do I want:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    __some_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

---

### SOLUTION FOUND:

**Update:** finally, I forge my own solution for this case and added it into my django-fields package, which is available on the GitHub: https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-fields

Specifically, if you want to have private fields in your models, then you have to inherit them from my [ModelWithPrivateFields](https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-fields/blob/master/src/django_fields/models.py#L33) class.

Example is available at [django-fields's unittests](https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-fields/blob/master/src/django_fields/tests.py#L356).

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: More to the point, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Daniel, I want to store some object's state in the database, but make it accessible only through it's methods. Incapsulation!

Comment: Joachim, I tried, of cause. Django raise exceptions like: "Cannot resolve keyword 'some_field' into field." when I try to execute something like that: "TestModel.objects.filter(some_field='blah')"

Comment: @AlexanderArtemenko: Of course. You've named it '__some_field' so 'some_field' won't work. It *should* work with `TestModel.objects.filter(_TestModel__some_field='blah')`, although I've never tried giving such a name to a Model field. About the 'why', see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: Beres, I know how private properties works in Python. But filter from your example does not works because Django thinks you are trying to make join, using double underscores.

Comment: Alexander, I'm thinking Beres had mistake and you should use TestModel.objects.filter(__some_field='blah'). Or rename __some_field to _some_field and use TestModel.objects.filter(_some_field='blah')

Comment: I've found the solution, if you are interested, then please see the updated original question.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do this?

If you just want to hide this field in admin interface you can use name of this field without leading underscore (it doesn't make any difference for Django, as far as I know) and register TestModelAdmin class:

```
class TestModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('some_field',)

admin.site.register(TestModel, TestModelAdmin)
```

Comment: No, I want to prevent other developers to use my class wrong way and keep it's state consistent.

Comment: I've found the solution, if you are interested, then please see the updated original question.

Comment: please place it as an answer so people can vote on your solution. Thanks