# Django Model Settings, but not Per-Object

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to set a custom set of variables once per model. For example, a model object might have the variables:

- has_meetings
- has_comments
- has_attachments

What I'm trying to accomplish is to specify the settings once per model, not once per instance of the model.

Originally, I tried:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
   has_comments = Boolean(default=True)
   has_meetings = Boolean(default=True)
```

But then I realized that will propagate in the admin to every single instance of the object. What I want to do is something that applies to any sub-classes of BaseModel, but not on every instance.

Has anyone come across this issue? What was the fix?

Comment: Where is "Boolean" being imported from?

Comment: You want it to be in the class but not in the instance? like a private field? will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180740/how-to-create-private-model-field-in-django

Comment: do you have class comments which is related with BaseModel ?

Comment: @A'zamMamatmurodov - I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @MichaelPatterson - It's just pseudocode to show you the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: @plumSemPy - That's sort of what I want, but a bit overkill. I was just wondering if there was a straightforward core Python/Django technique I was overlooking. I'm thinking along the lines of class Meta: abstract=True. It's a standard available option, but set on the model class. I looked into setting custom Meta variables, but that seems unavailable at the moment. What I worry about is that I set it in the BaseModel for default, but that it'll throw errors in the children if I set it manually.

Comment: @Craig, I mean you can use simple methods to detect has comments or has meetings

Comment: Well one technique you could use is to make a meta class yourself that generates the django classes. In your meta class you could put any custom fields you want. Then in Django your models can construct the classes they want from the meta class. Does that make sense?

Comment: what does it mean that `model` has_meeting? One db table has that status?

Comment: @seuling - Potentially, I want any model to have that option, but not the individual model instances. I want to specify that setting for the entire class of objects, not the instances.

Comment: @Craig Then what's meaning about have `has_comments` for your model? Can you give me a specific example? i.e.) your `Post` model has `has_comment`, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

You should use class var to accomplish  it:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    has_comments = True
    has_meetings = True
```

You can get it by:BaseModel.has_comments

Comment: I only want it to be available on the Model, not the model instances.

Comment: I was thinking of an approach like this as well. These really only exist on the model (class), not the instances. You can still kinda access it through an instance (read only, not write) but it is a class attribute not an instance attribute. What are the problems with this approach?